# VSCode not using Vcpkg acquired libraries

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-code, vcpkg

For some reason, VSCode is not able to see headers inside Vcpkg's installed libraries directory. I am using CMake build system on Ubuntu 17.04.
I am getting errors like:

```
[GCC] GL/glew.h: No such file or directory
```

My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

project ("RubeusCore")

FIND_PACKAGE(OpenGL REQUIRED)

# Include sub-projects.
add_subdirectory ("RubeusCore")
```

And RubeusCore/CMakeLists.txt is this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

link_directories(Source/)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES
    Source/*.cpp
)

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (RubeusCore "RubeusCore.cpp" "RubeusCore.h" ${SOURCES})

target_include_directories(RubeusCore PUBLIC ./Include)
include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(RubeusCore ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
```

.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${vcpkgRoot}/x64-linux/include/"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Also, I have specified the Vcpkg toolchain file in CMake once.

Comment: Try `"${vcpkgRoot}/installed/x64-linux/include/"`

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding the VCPKG Toolchain file in VSCODE `settings.json`

```
...

"cmake.configureSettings": {
        "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": "C:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
}
```